# Given $f(x)$ its inverse function, domain and range

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$f(x) = \frac{{2x + 3}}{{x - 1}},\left[ {x \in {R},x > 1} \right]$

I've got the inverse function to be:

${f^{ - 1}}(x) = \frac{{x + 3}}{{x - 2}}$

How would I go about working out the range and domain of this function? The range is possibly $f^{-1}(x)>1$ if im not mistaken, but how do I figure out the domain?

Comment: Note that you're missing a factor of $\frac{1}{5}$ for the inverse. Regardless, the range of the inverse is the domain of the original function. For its domain, you need to find the range of the original function. Can you think of a way to do that? Also, please indicate whether you're familiar with Möbius transformations.

Comment: We have $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x+3}{x-2}$. Your suggestion for the range is reasonable, but probably a more explicit answer is expected. The geometry will be clearer if we rewrite the original function as $2+\frac{5}{x-1}$. But you can also find the answers by manipulation of inequalities.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, thanks for that, that helps in visualising the function.

Comment: @JonathanY., Sorry i'm not familiar with mobius transformations, how would they help me?

Comment: Assad, as you tagged this with algebra-precalculus, I do not believe Möbius transformations would be appropriate to think about in this situation. It is a topic in complex analysis (or geometry).

Comment: @TylerClark said it; I thought there's a chance you've seen some of the properties of functions like $f$, but in this case you don't really need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick note, if you write $f^{-1}$ as a function of $x$ then the variable on the right hand should be $x$. So either $f^{-1}(y)=\frac{y+3}{y-2}$, which is perfectly fine to write, or $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x+3}{x-2}$, which is also perfectly fine to write.

To find the domain, you need to find the set of $x$ values such that there exists a value $y=f(x)$. Now, it seems that you're given a domain—you've written "$\left[x\in R,x>1\right]$". But if you weren't given that, you would want to find the largest possible such set of $x$ values. There's really only one real number $z$ such that we can't compute $f(z)$ for this $f$. Can you see what it is?

The range isn't always easy to find. The range is the set of $y$ values such that $y=f(x)$ for some $x$ in the range. Read that sentence over and over and over again until you understand it.

In this case the range *is* easy to find, since you've computed an inverse function. Then, the range of $f$ is just the domain of $f^{-1}$. Make sense?

Comment: Note that you could define $f$ on a superset of its current domain. Therefore, simply taking the largest possible domain of $f^{-1}$ (well, largest in $\mathbb{R}$, anyhow) won't reflect the range of $f$ as it is currently defined.

Comment: @JonathanY., Could you explain what you just said in simpler terms please..?

Comment: @Assad, certainly. If we only take a look at the equation for $f^{-1}$, we might think that $y=1$ is in its domain (and, indeed, it *could* be defined there). However, $f^{-1}(1)=-4$ (or $-\frac{4}{5}$, if my earlier computation was correct), which isn't in $f$'s domain as we've defined it. Therefore, there is no $x>1$ such that $f(x)=1$, implying that $1\not\in\mathcal{R}(f)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use that

- the domain of the inverse function is the range of the original function
- the range of the inverse function is the domain of the original function.

Comment: Does this hold true every time?

Comment: @Assad well, an inverse function does not always exist. But where one does, yes it holds true.